# Почему телеграмм-бот отправляет сообщение пользователю, но не отправляет в группу?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Бот для отправки сообщений

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string botToken = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN";
TelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient(botToken);

var client = (TelegramBotClient)botClient;
long chatId = YOUR_CHAT_ID;
string message = "Hello, world!";
client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, message).Wait();

Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Если chatId - id пользователя - сообщение проходит. Если id группы - падает исключение ApiRequestException: Bad Request: chat not found. В описании API (https://core.telegram.org/bots/tutorial#executing-...) указано, что для отправки сообщений в группу нужно просто заменить Id пользователя на id группы. Бот в группе с правами администратора. Id группы корректный. Почему падает исключение и не отправляется сообщение?

Comment: Не пользуюсь телеграм, но может `@channelusername` (как сказано в документации и в описании метода)?